# Pass Postfix' queue id to procmail

Tags: postfix-mta, procmail

Is there any way to pass the postfix' queue id (not the Message-ID: header) to a procmail command?

The reason behind is to have a procmail logfile containing the queue id for detailed logging about a handled message.

Comment: Good question. You might want to ask the [Postfix-users mailing list](http://www.postfix.org/lists.html). I am actually using several procmail recipes similar to what tripleee posted to distinguish local from remote mail. These provide the ID as a byproduct.

Answer (score 0):

Procmail can extract anything you can articulate a regex for. Without access to your local headers, this is speculative and somewhat *ad lib* but hopefully it should at least give you an idea.

```
# Put a newline in a string for the log message
NL="
"
:0
* ^Received: from .* \
    by yourserver\.example\.com \(Postfix)\
    with [A-Z]+ id \/[A-F0-9]+
{ LOG="Postfix id $MATCH$NL" }
```

The special token `\/` causes the matching text after it to be captured into the variable `$MATCH`.